# A Teacher's Mistake

Tags: mathematics, knowledge

A lady had two jobs. One of her jobs was to teach a high school math class part-time. . She was teaching math terminology (prefixes and suffixes).

"Un(i) is 1.

Bi is 2.

Tri is 3.

Quad is 4.

Quince is 5.

...

And a dozen is 13."

What was the teacher's other part time job?

Comment: -1 This is easily solvable with a quick internet search, or if you'd heard that single phrase before.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is plain trivia, no puzzle involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps she was a

> Baker

Because

> A [baker's dozen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dozen#Baker%27s_dozen) is 13.

Comment: I didn't know this reference! +1

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's an example of usage of this phrase? Such as "I bought a baker's dozen of eggs"? Sounds wierd... I think it's much simpler to say "thirteen".

Comment: @WhatsUp It's simpler but also less fun.

Comment: @WhatsUp I'd encountered the concept of "a baker's dozen" as part of advice about having spares/backups. The idea being that, in order to fulfil an order of a dozen (12) loaves of bread, the baker will make 13 (a "baker's dozen") so that after they're all baked, one can be discarded (or kept for use by the baker's family) whilst the customer is supplied with 12 good quality loaves. The baker who doesn't follow that advice will occasionally have to supply a customer with product that went totally wrong. (Also if 12 eggs needed for a baker's recipe it's good to have a spare in case of a bad egg)

Comment: Regarding "Quince" from the original question, rot13(n onxre zvtug hfr gung nf na vaterqvrag)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let's see what we have to work with here. First of all, notice that

> The teacher is terrible at her job. When teaching about "math" prefixes, she omits the most common math terms. Things that everyone knows - words like "Pentagon" (headquarters of the United States Department of Defense) is named as such because it has 5 sides - a common mathematical shape. But instead she teaches prefix "quint".
>
> Of course she omits the other prefixes, such as "mono-" (monorail, monologue) and "du-" (duplex, duet). And, the most egregious of all, "quint" is written as "quince", which is actually a fruit and not a prefix at all...
>
> Once she gets to 13, she forgoes the prefix "triskaideca-", as in triskaidecagon or triskaidekaphobia, and instead uses the word "dozen" which isn't even a prefix at all!

Another thing to note is

> Just because she tried to use the term "baker's dozen" would not necessarily mean that she's a baker. I'm not a baker, can I not use that term to refer to anything? Should I not be allowed to use the term "nautical mile" or "metric Ton" either because I'm not a sailor or in manufacturing? Obviously something else must be afoot here...

Drawing on all these observations

> Since we bear witness to how incompetent she is at teaching math, I would assume she would be just as incompetent at her other job. Since we also see that she used the word "dozen" as a prefix, and confused "quince" with "quint", I can only assume that her other part-time job is an English teacher!